# How to add my added environment variable?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to add an environmental variable. When I write `set` in cmd I want it to be there. How do I add it there?

I tried doing like this:

```
def read_json_dump():
    with open("apa.json") as f:
        a = json.load(f)
        for key, value in a.items():
            project_recipient_list = value['EMAIL']

            os.environ["$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS"] = project_recipient_list
```

When I write `print os.environ` I am able to find the environmental variable but not when I write `set` in cmd.

Comment: post a copy of your path variable from your machine

Comment: Changes to `os.environ` are temporary and only affect the current process or any subprocesses started with things like `os.system()` and `popen()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://code.activestate.com/recipes/159462-how-to-set-environment-variables/ it looks like you can't modify the current program's environment variables from python and have them persist, but there is a work around by running your python code from a bat file that also sets the desired variables.

> > Environment variables can be read with os.environ. They can be written (for sub-shells only) using os.putenv(key, value). However, there is no direct way to modify the global environment that the python script is running in. The indirect method shown [at the link] above writes a set command to a temporary batch file which is in the enclosing environment by another batch file used to launch the python script.
> >
> > ...arbitrary expressions can be evaluated and the result assigned to an environment variable. For security, the eval() function can be replaced with str().
> >
> > Usually, writing to an environment variable should be avoided in favor of sharing values through a pipe or a common data file. However, when it can't be avoided, the above technique is an effective, though hackish, work-around.

Comment: Yap, did a workaround just as you said and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Using os.environ won't be enough, those env vars won't persist, on windows if you want to persist variables you can use [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command, for example:

```
import os

os.system("setx $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS foo@foo.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.environ` sets environment variable only for the duration of the python program execution.

It won't be reflected outside.